# Is there no way to detect when a SwiftUI view is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an app that is built using a `NavigationSplitView` with a menu on the left and a map on the right. The left view controls the state of the map depending on what view is currently shown in the menu. Previously I saved my own routing state model for the navigation when `NavigationLinks` where activated using tags and selection. This made it possible to know the exact state of the apps routing at all times. With the new `NavigationStack`, we have to use `NavigationPath` which can not be monitored since the internal values are private.

Another option we had previously for knowing when a view was dismissed was to create a `StateObject` for the view when the view was created, then it will be deallocated as the view is dismissed. However that won't work in NavigationStack since the new `.navigationDestination` is called multiple times like any type of view rendering, making the `StateObject` allocate and deallocate just as many times.

And yes, I know about `.onAppear` and `.onDisappear`. However, these events are irrelevant in this situation since they can be called multiple times during the views lifecycle e.g. when another view is presented on top of the current view etc.

Is it possible to detect when a view truly disappears (is dismissed) in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer to how to detect when a screen disappears, but rather a solution to the first part of your problem.

With a `NavigationStack`, you *don't* have to use a `NavigationPath` object as the `path`.

The initialiser is:

```
init(path: Binding<Data>, @ViewBuilder root: () -> Root) where Data : MutableCollection, Data : RandomAccessCollection, Data : RangeReplaceableCollection, Data.Element : Hashable
```

so `path` can be a `Binding` of any array who's elements are `Hashable`. e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    enum Routing: Hashable {
        case screen1, screen2(String)
    }
    
    @State private var path: [Routing] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Show screen 1", value: Routing.screen1)
                NavigationLink("Show screen 2", value: Routing.screen2("Fred"))
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Routing.self) { screen in
                switch screen {
                case .screen1:
                    Text("This is screen 1")
                case let .screen2(name):
                    Text("This is screen 2 - name: \(name)")
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: path) { newValue in
            path.forEach { screen in
                print(screen)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As your `path` is not an opaque object you can use that to determine your app's current state.

Comment: Thanks for answering! And yes it is true that you can build your own path array that can be monitored, but by doing so you can only have one `.navigationDestination` at one level in the app (at least as I have understood it while I tried it). Since I need to have multiple levels of presentation in my app with multiple `.navigationDestination` I am forced to use the new `NavigationPath` since that is the only way to store multiple types of routing objects in the path.

Comment: Perhaps I could redesign my app to present all views in the whole app only from one `.navigationDestination` but I'd rather not if it can be avoided...

Comment: This is actually the way I did it eventually. Using my own array of "Route" objects and moving the presentation of every view in the app to one `.navigationDestination`. This enables me to monitor the path and thus also get to know when a view is dismissed from the view hierarchy. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Good idea… I think keeping the navigation all in one place makes it easier to keep a track of what's happening!